# Why there is no 'sign' method in Math object of typescript?

Tags: typescript

I noticed that there is no `Math.sign` in TypeScript, however it exists in pure JavaScript. I know there are other ways of getting the sign of a number but I am really curious about the reason why the authors didn't include this method.

This is what my compiler says if I try to use it:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean? Typescript has nothing do to with that.

Comment: The `Math` interface has `sign` in Typescript's default type definitions for es2015 at least.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es2015.core.d.ts#L118

Comment: Probably because you have selected a version of ecmascript, in your compilerOptions.lib property of your tsconfig.json, that doesn't have this method yet (i.e. es5).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see in your image that you have selected es5 as your ecmascript version (`lib.es5.d.ts`), which was released in 2009 and didn't include `Math.sign`. `Math.sign` was included in ES6 (aka ES2015).

In your `tsconfig.json`, change `compilerOptions > module` to `es2015` and add the version of ecmascript you want in lib. ie:

```
{
  // ... //
  "compilerOptions": {
    // ... //
    "module": "es2015",
    "lib": [/*...*/, "es2018"]

    // ... //
  }
  // ...//
}
```